# Extend Button OnClick

Tags: android, button, onclick, extends

I am trying to add specific behaviour to `Button`'s `onClick`, so when they are clicked they have the custom behaviour on top of the specific action for each button.

I have recently started developing for Android and have little experience on the inner quirks of events and UI classes.

WHat I tried, the buttom performs the custom behaviour I write in the extended class, but then doesn't perform the `onClick` action I assigned to the button specifically.

This is the custom `Button` I'm trying to do.

```
public class CooldownButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Timer cooldown;

    public CooldownButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CooldownButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CooldownButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        cooldown= new Timer();
        cooldown.schedule(cooldownRun(),0,500);
        setEnabled(false);
        //performClick();
    }

    private TimerTask cooldownRun()
    {
        return new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                cooldown.cancel();
                cooldown.purge();
                setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then I use it on `xml` layouts like this:

```
<CooldownButton android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:onClick="onBtnNextClick" />
```

`OnBtnNextClick` is never called.

```
public void onBtnNextClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnNext)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this document on making custom Views interactive: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html. I don't think you want to be implementing `OnClickListener` in your View.

Comment: try remove the onClick attribute from xml  and remove the implements from java CoolDownButton class and use this in java code create a variable of CoolDOwnClass and use this coolDownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){//paste all your logic inside this});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after following one of the comments indications.
It is not exactly the way I wanted to solve the issue but it gets close.

I scrapped the idea of making the click behaviour in a java class.
Instead I write a click listener in the MainActivity and then set the listener to all buttons I want to have this special click behaviour.

```
Button nextButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

The listener is as follows:

```
public View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()     {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Button btn = (Button) v;
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {Thread.sleep(1000); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){ btn.setEnabled(true); }
                });
            }
        }).start();


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnNext:
                    doSomething();
                break;
            //case R.id.foobar:
            //break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing you are disabling the button `setEnabled(false);` and then you want to perform some action on a next click `onBtnNextClick(View v)`. You cannot click a button a second time if it has been disabled when it was first clicked.

Comment: I want same click to run OnBtnNextClick and base class OnClick. In this case is to add a cooldown mechanic but I would like being able to add custom behaviours to the Onclick method.